# Finding only nodes that have more than one incoming relationship in neo4j using cypherquery

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

i have a neo4j database for learning this new fangled graph technology and i made nodes following this structure

```
(n:NewsArticle) -[r:about_place]-> (l:Location)
```

now what i want is slightly complicated/convoluted (or i seem to think it is) and being new to cypher i'm not able to completely express myself in this new syntax. please bear with me.

basically i have articles tagged with lots of locations. now, for a given day i have found all articles that are tagged with a certain location. once i have them, Now for those articles, i want to find out what other locations they are tagged with.

this code seems to do what i want it. (yaay)

```
MATCH (n:NewsArticle{date:"Jun-30-2015"})-[]->(l:Location{name:"India"})
MATCH (n:NewsArticle)-[r:about_place]->(m:Location)
return n,m
```

at this point i end up with 8 Locations and 132 news articles.

Now for the Tricky part. most of the 132 articles that i have have about_place relationships pointing to only 1 of the 8 locations, 
i do not want this. I want to find Articles within this set that have relationships to at least 2 of the Locations that i have found.

i came up with this query,

```
MATCH (n:NewsArticle{date:"Jun-30-2015"})-[]->(l:Location{name:"India"})
MATCH (n:NewsArticle)-[r:about_place]->(m:Location)
WITH m, count(r) as rel_cnt
WHERE rel_cnt > 2
MATCH (a:NewsArticle{date:"Jun-30-2015"})-[r:about_place]->(m:Location)
return a,m
```

it does give me some results but it does not do what i want. but if i change the **a** to **n** (to refer to the first 2 match statements) it becomes a syntax error although i feel that then it should give me the result i want.

**tl;dr i dont want to see location nodes that have only one news article pointing to them**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should return all the `NewsArticle` nodes with the `date` property of "Jun-30-2015" that have an `:about_place` relationship with `Location` India and at least one other location:

```
MATCH (n:NewsArticle {date:"Jun-30-2015"})-[:about_place]->(:Location {name: "India"})
MATCH (n)-[r:about_place]->(l:Location)
WITH collect(n) AS articles, l, count(r) AS num WHERE num > 2
RETURN l, articles, num
```

Comment: if i RETURN n,l at the end it gives me an error (l not defined?). i want to see all the location nodes as well as the article nodes that satisfy the criteria.

Comment: The `WITH` command wipes out any variables not indicated in the `WITH` statement so if you want to return locations as well you can either match for them again as answer by @ErnestoE shows, or add something like `COLLECT(l) as locations` to the `WITH` statement above.

Comment: if you can edit your answer to show the collect, i'll accept it as correct - you can just copy the query from my answer below - it was your answer that showed me the way though. so i'd rather accept your answer than mine

Comment: edit: added collect statement to include collection of acticles

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
MATCH (n:NewsArticle {date:"Jun-30-2015"})-[:about_place]->(:Location {name: "India"})
MATCH (n)-[r:about_place]->(l:Location)
WITH n, count(r) as num 
WHERE num > 2
MATCH (n)-[:about_place]->(l:Location)
RETURN n, l
```

You might want to exclude the original location from the result, for that you need to add an additional filter before the final RETURN.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer as the collect() statement which lets you carry variables through the WITH pipe.

```
MATCH (n:NewsArticle{date:"Jun-30-2015"})-[:about_place]->(l:Location{name:"India"})
MATCH (n:NewsArticle)-[r:about_place]->(loc:Location)
WITH loc,collect(n) as article, count(r) as num WHERE num > 2
RETURN loc,article
```